# How to use Angular Router inside a Service to navigate between components?

Tags: angular, angular-router

In my Ionic Angular app, I am adding a click event listener in my ***marker service*** below:

```
makeCapitalMarkers(map: L.map): void {
    map.on('popupopen', function () {
          if (document.querySelector('.norwayLink')) {
            const link = document.querySelector('.norwayLink')
            link.addEventListener('click', buttonClicked)
          }
        });

    function buttonClicked() {
        console.log('EXECUTED');
    }
}
```

The above code is called in my ***home component***:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.markerService.makeCapitalMarkers(this.map);
}
```

Currently, **"EXECUTED"** is being printed, so the method is being ran.

But when *buttonClicked()* is executed, I want to use the angular router to navigate to the ***chat component***.

I tried the below code:

```
function buttonClicked() {
    this.router.navigate(['/chat'])
}
```

> Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined

I declared router in the constructor as public, so I don't know why it's not being picked up in this function.

How can I navigate to the **Chat Component** using this function?

Should I be able to navigate routes within the service, or should this be done inside the **Home Component**?

Here are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./home/home.module').then( m => m.HomePageModule)},
  {
    path: 'chat',
    loadChildren: () => import('./chat/chat.module').then( m => m.ChatPageModule)
  },
];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `this` inside a `function() { }` refers to the function itself. Instead declare the function on the class, and call it inside arrow functions.

```js
makeCapitalMarkers(map: L.map): void {
  map.on('popupopen', () => {
    if (!eventHandlerAssigned && document.querySelector('.norwayLink')) {
      const link = document.querySelector('.norwayLink')
      link.addEventListener('click', () => {
        this.buttonClicked();
      });
      eventHandlerAssigned = true
    }
  });    
}

buttonClicked() {
  this.router.navigate(['/chat']);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you inject the `Router` in the service like this?

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private router: Router)
...
```